# How to resolve errors in my Search component? React + Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

Got an interesting problem and I dont know how to solve it. I built a Search component in my react app that searches in my Firebase realtime database and gives back the posts based on the search value.

It works fine but when I actually search for something, even though it returns the results correctly, it gives me a bunch of errors. (I'll paste them below)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

My component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Search } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import { db } from '../../firebase';

class SearchSection extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.resetComponent();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { onSetPosts } = this.props;

        db.onGetPosts().on('value', snapshot => onSetPosts(snapshot.val()));
    }

    resetComponent = () =>
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, results: [], value: '' });

    handleResultSelect = (e, { result }) =>
        this.setState({ value: result.createdBy });

    handleSearchChange = (e, { value }) => {
        const { posts } = this.props;

        this.setState({ isLoading: true, value });

        // eslint-disable-next-line
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (value.length < 1) return this.resetComponent();

            const re = new RegExp(_.escapeRegExp(value), 'i');
            const isMatch = result => re.test(result.createdBy);

            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                results: _.filter(posts, isMatch)
            });
        }, 300);
    };

    render() {
        const { isLoading, value, results } = this.state;

        const resultRenderer = ({ createdAt, createdBy, message }) => (
            <div>
                <p>{createdBy}</p>
                <p>{createdAt}</p>
                <p>{message}</p>
            </div>
        );

        resultRenderer.propTypes = {
            createdAt: PropTypes.number,
            createdBy: PropTypes.string,
            message: PropTypes.string
        };

        return (
            <Search
                loading={isLoading}
                onResultSelect={this.handleResultSelect}
                onSearchChange={_.debounce(this.handleSearchChange, 500, {
                    leading: true
                })}
                results={results}
                resultRenderer={resultRenderer}
                value={value}
            />
        );
    }
}

/* Connect the state to this component */
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    posts: state.postState.posts
});

/* This is to store the users coming from the database to the Redux store */
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSetPosts: posts => dispatch({ type: 'POSTS_SET', posts })
});

SearchSection.propTypes = {
    onSetPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    posts: PropTypes.shape({
        createdAt: PropTypes.number,
        createdBy: PropTypes.string,
        lastModifiedAt: PropTypes.number,
        message: PropTypes.string,
        uid: PropTypes.string
    }).isRequired
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchSection);
```

Here I'm getting the POSTS from the redux store and using them as prop for the component.

This is the results that I'm getting when I search for something:
[image: results]

The errors I'm getting are:

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'results' supplied to 'Search'.`

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'title' is marked as required in 'SearchResult', but its value is 'undefined'.`

`Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.`

`Warning: React does not recognize the 'createdAt' prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase 'createdat' instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.`

I get this last error 4 times, for all my fields in the results .. createdAt, createdBy, lastmodifiedAt, message .. even though I'm not passing these props directly.

If that helps, i'm trying to use semantic ui react's search component.
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search/

Please let me know if you need any other information.

EDIT: The SearchResult component if needed: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Search/SearchResult.js
(It is predefined by semantic)

Comment: Can you share SearchResult component code as well

Comment: Sure, I edited my post :) It is predefined by semantic though

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I get the same thing.  I'm using version:     "semantic-ui-react": "^0.84.0",

Comment: No I actually ended up going with a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong per se. It's a bug within the Semantic Ui React Library. See here:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1681

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/1141

Unfortunately, you will need to either do a hacky work-around or ignore the warnings until/if they fix the library. :/